# Use Dot Before Var in SCSS

Tags: css, loops, for-loop, sass, gulp

This scss works if I remove the dot before `#{$i}s`.

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
  #a#{$i} {
      animation-duration: .#{$i}s;
    }
}
```

However, when I include the dot, Gulp gives me this error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...ation-duration:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".#{$i}s;"
        on line 3 of app/sass/_common.scss
>>       animation-duration: .#{$i}s;
   -------------------------^
```

I need this dot because I want `.1s`, `.2s`, `.3s` and so on. How do I make this work?

Comment: I've Google `dote` and got a response. Now I'm not sure if its a typo. (but in sass it is).

Comment: I mean dot. sorry.

Comment: Then with `.#` do you mean a class or an id? because that is the misunderstanding as it would not be interpreted as both.

Comment: I mean 0.#{$i}s => 0.1s. So it is not class, it is just dot before milliseconds in animation-duration and  # is the way u use variable in scss loop.

Comment: Then now you know where the error came from. I'm not sure but try to prepend a `0` before the `.` as it would let the compiler know you mean a number instead of a class.

Comment: @Xorifelse it make sense, but it still does not work.`Error: Invalid CSS after "...ion-duration: 0": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".#{i}s;"
        on line 3 of app/sass/_common.scss
>>       animation-duration: 0.#{i}s;
   --------------------------^`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
animation-duration: $i * 0.1s;
```